# “To agree with someone”: is that prepositional phrase an adverbial or a nominal one?

Tags: prepositional-phrases, syntactic-analysis, transitivity, grammatical-roles, predicate-frames

In this sentence:

> I agree **with you**.

What is the function of the prepositional phrase ”with you” there? Is it an adverb or noun?

If it is an adverb, then what type of adverb is this?

Comment: Could you please show us an example of what you mean by a prepositional phrase “functioning as a noun”? Prepositional phrases normally fulfill adverbial or adjectival roles as **modifiers** of verbs and nouns respectively. Actual  **substantive** uses fulfilling nominal roles (like for subjects or objects) are few and far between, if at all.

Comment: The prepositional phrase "with you" in that sentence is adverbial, not nominal.  It is modifying the verb "agree," not the noun/pronoun "I," i.e., describing the manner in which "I" agrees, not "I" itself.

Answer (score 1):

"With" is always a preposition (http://partofspeech.org/what-part-of-speech-is-with/).  Adverbs answer one of these: how, when, where, why, to what extent, how often or how much.

Answer (score -1):

"To agree with someone" isn't a prepositional phrase.  It's a verb phrase or a gerund phrase, "to agree" being the infinitive form and a gerund form of the verb "agree."

"With someone" is a prepositional phrase.  Whether it is adverbial or adjectival depends on whether "to agree" is serving as an infinitive or as a gerund.

Examples:

> You are going to agree with someone.

In the above sentence, "to agree" is in its infinitive form, so "with someone" is adverbial.

> I would prefer to agree with someone.

In the above sentence, "to agree" is in its gerund form, meaning the same thing as the participial gerund "agreeing with someone" (i.e., the thing that I would prefer), so it is adjectival.

In the sentence "I agree with you," the prepositional phase "with you" is adverbial as it modifies the verb "agree" (i.e., describes the manner in which I agree).

Now, sere you to say, "I, with you, agree," or "I agree, with you," then that would be adjectival.  That's because it would modifying "I," not "agree," the meaning changing to the two of us together jointly agreeing with someone or something else.

Comment: This is complete nonsense: ***to agree* is not** ‘a gerund form of the verb “agree”’ in anybody’s version of English grammar. Infinitives are not gerunds! Just precisely what is it that you purport an English ‘gerund’ to be? What’s your source of that so-called definition?